# Provide alternative solution for mouse events issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clipboard

I am working on a clipboard functionality, but I am facing some mouse-events related issues.

In the code snippet below, my clipboard functionality works only when I remove `label tag` and  `style="display:none" class="hide"`.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Copy to Clipboard with ZeroClipboard, Flash 10 and jQuery</title>
    <link href="_assets/css/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="_assets/js/ZeroClipboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myfunc2() {
            var selectedobj = document.getElementById('texter');
            if(selectedobj.className=='hide'){  //check if classname is hide 
                selectedobj.style.display = "block";
                selectedobj.readOnly=true;
                selectedobj.className ='show';
            } else {
                selectedobj.style.display = "none";
                selectedobj.className ='hide';
            }
        }
    </script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
            clip.setText('');  
            jQuery('#copy-button').click(function(){
                clip.setText(jQuery('#texter').val());
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
            clip.setText(''); // will be set later on mouseDown
            clip.addEventListener('mouseDown', function (client) {
                // set text to copy here
                clip.setText(jQuery('#texter').val());    
                // alert("mouse down"); 
            });
            clip.glue('copy-button');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <label  onmouseover="myfunc2()">Click here</label> 
    <textarea name="texter" id="texter"  style="display:none" class="hide"   readonly>sdfdsfsdfgdfdfg</textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Copy to clipboard" id="copy-button" />
</body>
```

Comment: Replicating this issue on jsfiddle will improve your chances of getting better and quicker answer.

Comment: why cannot you guyz directly copy code into jsfiddle and test it..?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
        clip.setText('');  
        $('#copy-button').click(function(){
            clip.setText($('#texter').val());
        }); 


        clip.mousedown(function (client) {
            // set text to copy here
            clip.setText($('#texter').val());    
            // alert("mouse down"); 
        });
        clip.glue('copy-button');
    });
```

I've coupled the two .ready functions and removed the 2nd ZeroClipboard.Client() instance, as its no longer needed. I've also bound the mousedown event differently, see jQuery [mousedown() doc](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) for details.

and bring in a newer version of jquery change this; http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js
to;
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js

Comment: try including  a newer version of jquery 1.3 is old,

Comment: its ok bro.. np! Still not working.. thanks for your time..  :)